# Book Recommender System Using ML, Streamlit Error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, streamlit, web-development-server, anaconda3

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "E:\Book Recommender system\env\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script exec(code, module.__dict__)`

When I run the following command
`streamlit run app.py` then this error will appear that I have shown above. I don't know why this error is displaying again and again.

I have tried streamlit community solutions, I asked the solution from GPT also but nothing happens. asked many of my friends and teachers also.

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I have similar issues and it was solved with versions of streamlit library (there are some updates that are not perfectly working sometimes). So my advice to check the version errors

Comment: I have resolved the error, and now there are no issues remaining. thankyou